# Using ITextSharp to generate XPS documents instead of PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, xps

I'm using ITextSharp to generate PDF files. Is it also possible to generate XPS files? And if yes, how?

Can't find any documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTextSharp is a library specifically built to generate PDF files, so that is not going to create XPS files for you.  The [System.Windows.Xps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms604617.aspx) namespace provides you with methods for writing XPS documents from your code for .net 3.5 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

An Idea: You could try creating the PDF using iTextSharp, then converting it to XPS using GhostScript to print to an XPS printer driver?

Comment: Yes that would be possible, but is this possible doing programatically?

Comment: You can print to a named printer using ghostscript programatically, havent tried a printer driver. I have a C# GhostScript wrapper you could try (send me an email, address on profile) .. it should be the same process, ie xmp printer driver installed on machine, but you wold need to try and send a filename parameter somehow..

Comment: This would require that ghostscript and the printers are installed on the computer i'mrunning the application?

Comment: @Roflcoptr: That is true, I am assuming that you want to keep the existing generated PDF, in this case you would need something to interpret the PDF. Alternatovely you could either 1) write new code to build the XPS, or write some kind of intermediate code to generate XML or even HTML that can be used to generate PDF and/or XPS?

Comment: Maybe this is the better solution. I saw that there are libraries to generate XPS from PDF but they are all far to expensive